# How to export DynamoDB table data without the point in time recovery?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to export data from a DynamoDB table for the last 15 days, but
unfortunately, the point in time recovery is not active. So I can't use the new DynamoDB export to S3 feature because it's not retroactive.

I have tried using the AWS Data Pipeline to export the DynamoDB data to S3
but is it retroactive?

If so I have tried to export the data but the Pipeline is failing with
the TableBackupActivity with a status of cancelled. Didn't find anything in the log bucket nor in the
Data Pipeline console but only this

```
@failureReason Resource not healthy: Jobflow retired
```

How to know if this is due to the Read Capacity Unit of the DynamoDB Table?

Comment: So you want to export data that you don't have, because you haven't enabled point in time recovery? Unless you have enabled DynamoDB streams and continuously write the changes somewhere (which seems unlikely) you're probably out of luck :/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot backup data to s3 natively without the Point in time Recovery enabled.

Another way of doing this would be reading the complete database and saving it as JSON. And during the time of recovery re-populating your disaster recovery database with your JSON file.
Amazon has an article for populating dynamodb from JSON file here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-scalable-serverless-import-process-for-amazon-dynamodb/

Comment: I would strongly recommend not to use this answer as this (a) takes up the table's read capacity (by doing a scan) of the table and thus impacts performance (b) take much longer than needed

Comment: @Yuki you are right. This is a very resource extensive process. It is just that there is no other native way.

Comment: You also have aws backup. Have you tried it?